# CSV file - New columns are not formed

Tags: php, file, csv

I am trying to create a CSV file like this:

```
Name    surname
disha   goyal
```

Code goes like this:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('filse.csv', 'w');

fwrite($fp, 'Name');
fwrite($fp, "\t");
fwrite($fp, "Surname");
fwrite($fp, "\n");
fwrite($fp, 'disha');
fwrite($fp, "\t");
fwrite($fp, 'goyal');

fclose($fp);
?>`
```

Output is this:

```
Namesurname
dishagoyal
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at this in an editor/app that displays tabs correctly...?

Comment: I am using.. Microsoft excel sheet open it .. I need to look for it settings..? Is dat u r asking? can u help me getting it exactly.. to change its settings.. coz.. i really think this might be the issue.

Comment: Excel probably does not import TSV files without you going through the File > Import wizard correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While opening the document in Excel, you must specify that the delimiter you use is tab.

By default, a csv file is assumed to be comma separated.

You can also use comma instead of tab for proper output without any settings.

Comment: Yes.. Karan Punamiya.. i got your point, but it does not alerts me for specifying the TSV.